# typesafe keyof partial object construction

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trieng to set a state property in a react component in a generic way.
The following code works but ignores typechecks:

```
type ComponentState = ""|"OK"|"WARNING"|"ERROR"|"UNKOWEN";
interface SelfCheckState {
    db: ComponentState;
    system: ComponentState;
    //[...]
}

fetchComponentState(component:keyof SelfCheckState) {
    return fetch('/api/state/'+component).then((res)=>{
        if(res.status != 200) return Promise.reject(res);
        return res.json();
    }).then(res=>{
        //[...]
        const state: ComponentState = res.state;
        let x: any = {};
        x[component] = state;
        this.setState(x);
    });
}
```

Is there a typesafe way that avoids `let x: any = {}`?

Comment: Are all properties of type `ComponentState` ?

Comment: Would `let x = {} as SelfCheckState;` work?

Comment: @Saravana yes, thanks